# ¿Por qué al hacer un registro a mi Base de Datos en SQLServer desde mis TextBox me da valores vacíos?

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio, .net, wpf

Estoy desarrollando un proyecto en WPF. Al hacer mi INSERT desde mis TextBox y mi ComboBox me da registros vacíos en mi Base de Datos. Aquí la estructura

```
 <TextBox Style="{StaticResource tbox_PeopleIconPlaceholder}" Grid.Row="1" Tag="Nombre" x:Name="txtnombre"/>

            <TextBox Style="{StaticResource tbox_PeopleLastNamePlaceholder}" Grid.Row="2" Tag="Apellidos" x:Name="txtapellidos"/>

            <TextBox Style="{StaticResource tbox_EmailIconPlaceholder}" Grid.Row="3" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Tag="Correo Electrónico" x:Name="txtemail"/>

            <StackPanel Grid.Row="4" Orientation="Horizontal">
                <ComboBox Style="{DynamicResource ComboBoxStyle3}" Height="35" Width="65" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0 10 0 10" x:Name="cmbLada" Loaded="cmbLada_Loaded" />

                <TextBox Margin="5 0 0 0" Style="{StaticResource tbox_NumberIconPlaceholder}" Tag="Número de Teléfono" x:Name="txtnumtelefonico"/>
            </StackPanel>
```

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y de paso ganes tu primer medalla, también es muy importante que leas [ask] para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que sea bien recibida por la comunidad mejorando así, tus chances de obtener buenas respuestas.

Comment: No vemos el código que llama a la base de datos, ni los parámetros del procedimiento almacenado, si hay; ni las llamadas a entity framework, si hay... Faltan muchos detalles. Por favor edita tu pregunta y añade la información necesaria

Comment: Hola Miguel, bienvenido a StackOverflow, con lo que publicas es imposible decirlo.

Answer (score 0):

Tienes que enlazar los textbox a una propiedad de la clase que estes usando para mapear la tabla de la base de datos. Ejemplo del textbox:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Mipropiedad}">
```

Y la clase que mapea la tabla de la base de datos sería por ejemplo:

```
 Public class Alumno{
    private string _nombre;
    public string Mipropiedad{ get => _nombre; set{ _nombre=value;}}
 }
```

Tendrías que enlazar la clase que representa la tabla con el fichero xaml donde tienes los textbox.